# Service worker in Python flask application - Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, flask, service-worker

I'm able to register a service worker successfully but when I try a simple console log I get the following result - [dev tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuT5l.png)

It looks like some kind of routing error but I don't know how to fix it.

my code looks like this

offerings.js file

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // Register a service worker hosted at the root of the
    // site using a more restrictive scope.
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/static/js/sw.js').then(function() {
        console.log('Service worker registration succeeded:');
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log('Service worker registration failed:');
    });
} else {
    console.log('Service workers are not supported.');
}
```

sw.js file

```
console.log('Hello')
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to your routes file:

```
@app.route('/sw.js', methods=['GET'])
def sw():
    return app.send_static_file('sw.js')
```

Then, place your `sw.js` file directly in the `static` directory, not the `js` directory. In your `offerings.js` file, use a relative path (i.e. `../sw.js`). Let me know if that works.

Comment: After finding lots of suggestions where I have to add a header (serverside) this is nice and simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it running by writing the following code

```
from flask import make_response, send_from_directory
@app.route(‘/sw.js’)
def sw():
    response = make_response(send_from_directory(‘static’, file name=‘sw.js’))
    #change the content header file
    response.headers[‘Content-Type’]=‘application/javascript’
    return response
```

Comment: ```filename=``` not  ```file name=```